# Script to read multiple input file and writing multiple output file for each input file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scripting, python-2.6

I have multiples input files in format like below which have to be processed.

Input file path `/tmp/input`.

```
1.1.1.txt
1.1.2.txt
1.1.3.txt
```

But, I want to have output files for each input file in another folder suppose (`/tmp/outputsmgr`) like below:

```
1.1.1_output.csv
1.1.2_output.csv
1.1.3_output.csv
```

The issues are:

- Firstly, I am not able to write the output files in another/different folder
- Secondly, all input files data after processing getting merged in one file in input folder only like below instead of separate output file for each input file

All the below files contains same data instead `1.1.1.txt` data should be in file `1.1.1_output.csv` and file `1.1.2.txt` data should be in file `1.1.2_output.csv`.

```
1.1.1.txt_output.csv
1.1.2.txt_output.csv
1.1.3.txt_output.csv
```

How can I modify the below code to get the desired result?

```
import os
import csv
import re

def parseFile(fileName):
    # We are using a dictionary to store info for each file
    data = list()
#    data = dict()

    fh = open(fileName, "r")
    lines = fh.readlines()[1:]
    for line in lines:
        line = line.rstrip("\n")
        if re.search("sessmgr", line):
            splitted = line.split()
            temp = dict()
            temp["CPU"] = splitted[0]
            temp["facility"] = splitted[1]
            temp["instance"] = splitted[2]
            temp["cpu-used"] = splitted[3]
            temp["cpu-allc"] = splitted[4]
            temp["mem-used"] = splitted[5]
            temp["mem-allc"] = splitted[6]
            temp["files-used"] = splitted[7]
            temp["files-allc"] = splitted[8]
            temp["sessions-used"] = splitted[9]
            temp["sessions-allc"] = splitted[10]
#            print (splitted[2])

            data.append(temp)
#            continue;
#    print (data)
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inputsDirectory = "/tmp/input"
    outputDirectory = "/tmp/outputsmgr"
    path = os.path.abspath(inputsDirectory)
    pathout = os.path.abspath(outputDirectory)
    fileLists = ["{0}/{1}".format(path,x) for x in os.listdir(outputDirectory)]
    fileList = ["{0}/{1}".format(path,x) for x in os.listdir(inputsDirectory)]
#    print(fileList)

    csvRows = []
    for file in fileList:
        newRow = parseFile(file)
        csvRows.append(newRow)

#    print(csvRows)
    for files in fileList:
        outputFile = "output.csv"
        csvfile = open(os.path.join(files + "_" + outputFile), 'w')
        fieldnames = ["CPU",
                      "facility",
                      "instance",
                      "cpu-used",
                      "cpu-allc",
                      "mem-used",
                      "mem-allc",
                      "files-used",
                      "files-allc",
                      "sessions-used",
                      "sessions-allc"]
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        headers = {}
        for n in writer.fieldnames:
            headers[n] = n
        writer.writerow(headers)
#       writer.writeheader()
        for row in csvRows:
            for obj in row:
                print (obj)
                writer.writerow(obj)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code below will do what you want. It processes the files in the input directory sequentially and the results returned from the `parseFile()` function get written to the corresponding output file in the output directory. It's important to get a new set of `csvRows` from each input file and write (just) those to each output file.

The code assumes the `outputDirectory` already exists, but if that's not the case, then you'll need to add code to create it before processing any of the files. **Hint:** use `os.path.exists() and os.path.isdir()` in conjunction with `os.makedirs()`.

```
import csv
import os
import re


def parseFile(filePath, fieldnames, target_re=r"sessmgr"):
    """ Yield lines of file matching target regex. """
    with open(filePath, "r") as file:
        next(file)  # Skip/ignore first line.
        for line in file:
            if re.search(target_re, line):
                yield dict(zip(fieldnames, line.split()))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    OUTPUT_FILE_SUFFIX = "output.csv"
    inputsDirectory = "/tmp/input"
    outputDirectory = "/tmp/outputsmgr"
    fieldnames = ("CPU", "facility", "instance", "cpu-used", "cpu-allc", "mem-used",
                  "mem-allc", "files-used", "files-allc", "sessions-used",
                  "sessions-allc")

    input_dir = os.path.abspath(inputsDirectory)
    output_dir = os.path.abspath(outputDirectory)

    for in_filename in os.listdir(input_dir):
        in_filepath = os.path.join(input_dir, in_filename)
        print('in_filepath:  "{}"'.format(in_filepath))

        in_rootname = os.path.splitext(in_filename)[0]
        out_filename = in_rootname + "_" + OUTPUT_FILE_SUFFIX
        out_filepath = os.path.join(output_dir, out_filename)
        print('out_filepath: "{}"'.format(out_filepath))

        with open(out_filepath, 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerows(parseFile(in_filepath, fieldnames))
```

Comment: @as6656: You're welcome. See update — also note that I did not test the code with Python 2.6 since I don't have it installed.

Comment: @martineau..i have similar issue with other telnet code..will post the question...can you please check that